# GitHub Action move issue on project when issue is linked to a Pull Request

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request, github-issues, github-projects

I am trying to automate my project boards. I would like an action to trigger when someone opens a Pull Request and links it to a issue on the board, then the issue would be moved to "In Review".

I imagine once I trigger by a pull_request, this information would be seen on the given environment variables. But I dumped all of them and I could not find any reference to the issue I am linking and would like to move on the project board.

Can someone give me some light on what I could do to achieve this result?

Comment: I would suggestion reading this: https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/automating-your-project.

Comment: @tj-cappelletti I read, but could not find where which issue is linked to a pull request?

Answer (score 0):

First you can reference an issue in your commit message described in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue). Then you can set up [built-in](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/automating-your-project/using-the-built-in-automations) automations for the project board. If you then push something to your repository and create a merge request, the issue should be automatically linked and moved to the column "In Review".

Comment: But I do not want it to work when I merge the Pull Request, I already have an action for that. When merged, the issue moves to "Done". What I want is that when i reference the issue on the description of the Pull Request, it moves it to "In Review".

Answer (score 0):

We actually have a github action that does this for us now, it looks something like

```yaml
name: Callable Front End Issue Tracker

on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  manage-project:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      issues: write
    steps:
      - name: Move PR to Review Needed
        uses: leonsteinhaeuser/project-beta-automations@v2.1.0
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request_target' && github.event.action == 'review_requested' }}
        with:
          gh_token: ${{ secrets.SMG_TOKEN }}
          organization: MyOrg
          project_id: 3
          resource_node_id: ${{ github.event.pull_request.node_id }}
          move_related_issues: true
          status_value: 'Dev: Review Needed ' # Target status
```

Running the actions in [debug mode](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging) helped a ton with seeing what the event names and actions names were supposed to be.